# Linker Error with log4cxx

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I'd like to use Apache log4cxx and am running into a problem.  I'm running on Debian 8 and installed [log4cxx using](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/liblog4cxx10-dev)

```
apt-get install liblog4cxx10-dev
```

I have embedded one of the code snippets in the [Documentation Page](https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/usage.html) into the code below:

```
#include <log4cxx/logger.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr logger(log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("com.foo"));
    int i = 10;
    const char* region = "World";

    LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, "Simple message text.")
    LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, "Hello, " << region)
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, L"Iteration " << i)
    LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, "e^10 = " << std::scientific << exp(10.0))
    LOG4CXX_WARN(logger, L"" << i << L" is the number of the iteration.")

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with Eclipse CDT (gcc 5.3.0 built from source) I get the following linker errors:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/tester.cxx
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/tester.d" -MT"src/tester.o" -o "src/tester.o" "../src/tester.cxx"
Finished building: ../src/tester.cxx

Building target: logtest
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o "logtest"  ./src/tester.o   -llog4cxx
./src/tester.o: In function `main':
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:9: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str[abi:cxx11](log4cxx::helpers::CharMessageBuffer&)'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:9: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:10: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str[abi:cxx11](log4cxx::helpers::CharMessageBuffer&)'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:10: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:11: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str[abi:cxx11](std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >&)'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:11: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:12: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str[abi:cxx11](std::ostream&)'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:12: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:13: undefined reference to `log4cxx::helpers::MessageBuffer::str[abi:cxx11](std::basic_ostream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >&)'
makefile:45: recipe for target 'logtest' failed
/home/andand/workspace/logtest/Debug/../src/tester.cxx:13: undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&, log4cxx::spi::LocationInfo const&) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [logtest] Error 1
```

I double checked where apt installed the libraries:

```
root@starsim-dev:/home/andand# find / -name *log4cxx*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so.10.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblog4cxx.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/liblog4cxx.pc
/usr/include/log4cxx
/usr/include/log4cxx/private/log4cxx_private.h
/usr/include/log4cxx/log4cxx.h
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cxx10
/usr/share/doc/liblog4cxx10-dev
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/liblog4cxx10
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/liblog4cxx10-dev
/var/cache/apt/archives/liblog4cxx10-dev_0.10.0-4_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/liblog4cxx10_0.10.0-4_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10-dev.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/liblog4cxx10-dev.md5sums
```

The documentation on Apache's website isn't entirely clear what other library dependencies exist.  Does anybody have some insight into what I'm missing?

Comment: did you ever figure out the issue about undefined reference to `log4cxx::Logger::forcedLog(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Level ? Thanks.

Comment: @caot No.  I didn't need all of the features in log4cxx, so I just rolled my own to meet my needs, and that worked well enough.  I may go back and try again, though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same set of linker errors trying to use log4cxx on Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to get their code snippets to work - including the one above - by adding the following additional Apache libs to my MakeFile

```
LIBS+= -llog4cxx -laprutil-1 -lapr-1
```

Make sure to list them in the above order.

Comment: please send a complete solution with enough description to understand what are you doing in your code and how the problem solved.

Comment: Updated answer above. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Turns out this is something which seems to have been fixed.  I made a couple minor adjustments and it now compiles just fine, even without additional Apache libraries.